# Create UIView in Interface Builder Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, interface-builder, uistoryboard

I have searched for what I want to do but all the answers seem to predate storyboards in iOS, so i'm hoping there is a new and easier way to do it.

I have a view controller that needs the same UIView multiple times. I could create and position them programatically but it would really help me if I could design them in a storyboard and position them visually there. I would prefer not to create an extra .xib file.

I am developing for iOS 6 and there is a new Container View but i cannot seem to understand how it works, maybe somebody can explain it to me. I managed to make the view appear but I cannot communicate between the UIView in the container and the parent UIViewController.
I have also seen a way to do this with segues but they said that they shouldn't be used in that way.

Comment: Why dont you create one then copy paste the uiview multiple times? There are several ways to do this but it depends on the behavior you want

Comment: I want the UIView to handle all the subviews it has inside like a normal custom UIView made programatically in its own class (needs to respond to properties, etc). Also, I will probably have to change the things in it many times during development so I would prefer not having to copy them again and just have the changes propagate.

Comment: I have 0 experience with iOS 6 but in MY experience it is not possible to create custom objects like this in iOS, however you can easily use a XIB a custom class and a dummy object to achieve something similar. You would design in the xib with its custom class and use the dummy on the storyboard to take its location and frame.

Answer (score 0):

## No trick, no gimmick

@Chiquis solution is the way to go.

Treat Storyboard as a **set of XIB**, all neatly organized under a single roof:

1. Copy and paste your UIView in as many `UIViewController` as you see fit
2. Connect each UIView to its parent `UIViewController` using IBOutlets